# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml

Good afternoon all, I am in real need of help. Have been trying to resolve this issue for some time now and I can't figure it out. I am getting the following error on a OnePlus 7 Pro Device.

I have looked at each of the individual items and checked that the width and the height are set. I have also checked for duplicates and consistency surrounding XML formation.

Would appreciate any help.

`12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.X.X, PID: 11338
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:798)
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7766)
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7958)
12-03 15:14:18.662 11338 11338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.(FrameLayout.java:439)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rl3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/window_background_color">

<!-- Toolbar with spinner -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@color/text_and_icon_color"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<!-- Admob banner -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/window_background_color"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


<!-- Map content -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView" />

<!-- Location list -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:background="@color/window_background_color"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circleprogressbar_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circleprogressbar_height"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:mlpb_enable_circle_background="true" />

<!-- Fab map type button -->
<net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabLayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fabLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_margin"
    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/material_background_color"
    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/light_primary_color"
    app:fab_icon="@mipmap/ic_layers_grey600_36dp" />

<!-- Fab my location button -->
<net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_margin"
    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent_color"
    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/light_primary_color"
    app:fab_icon="@mipmap/ic_my_location_white_36dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exception message pointing the problem clearly. You missing `layout_width` attribute in your layout

Comment: add your full xml in the post not in comment

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman thank you, I have put the XML in the post

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the android:width or android:layout_weight instead of android:layout_width in your XML file.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It's way easier to help, if you paste your XML file and/or code (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Seems it couldn`t find @dimen/circleprogressbar_width

Comment: I hardcoded in the value and it make no difference. Still having the error.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue. The issue was relating to a SnackBar library thay I was using.